# Can I optimize a heavy main-thread JavaScript visual effect from a library?

Tags: javascript, performance, html5-canvas, particles, particles.js

Usually, I try to make all of my visual effects with CSS. But sometimes, be it by explicit client request or because the desired effect is too complicated for CSS, I need to use JS libraries. One such example is [Particles.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/).

Despite the description stating it to be lightweight, using it significantly impacts my PageSpeed Insights score. For example, take a look at [the Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fvincentgarreau.com%2Fparticles.js%2F) for [the library's demo page](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/), which is pretty simple. The overall score is pretty good, thanks to the page's simplicity, but both rendering and script evaluation times are high.

If I don't have any control over the library itself and there isn't a more efficient library available*, what can I do to improve performance?

What methods can I use to minimize the impact that such a heavy visual effects script has? Can I, for example, only load the effect if the device is powerful enough to handle it? Is it possible to de-prioritize the effect so that any lag won't affect the rest of the page?

*That may or may not be the case for this particular library, but let's assume there isn't a better one.

Comment: *That may or may not be the case for this particular library, but let's assume there isn't a better one. *ehm*... tsParticles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the requestAnimationFrame (and libraries that use it) will always add to the render and script evaluation time. This is not necessarily a bad thing, but you don't always have control over an external library.

One option is to add a layer to the animation. Something like this will add very little overhead to the animation, but will cancel it if the frame rate starts dipping down:

It looks something like this:

```js
let startTime = Performance.now() // precise start time
const animation = new MyAnimationLib()
const updateLoop = newTime => {
  const delta = newTime - startTime
  startTime = newTime
  if (delta > 1000 / 60) { 
    animation.cancel() // 60 fps min to keep running animation
    return // exit the loop
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(updateLoop)
}

// Start monitoring the animation
requestAnimationFrame(updateLoop)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a promising idea. There is something I don't understand. How is the `Animation()` object you're referencing linked to my library? How does it know what you're telling it to cancel? How does `animation.cancel()` affect the library instance I've created?

Comment: I should have been more specific. Animation represents your animation library. Does the library offer you a way to cancel the effect?

Comment: Oh I see. I got confused since `Animation` is a thing. I should've connected the dots. Well most do have a method to destroy the effect afterwards. The one in the example doesn't explicitly, but deleting its canvas should do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I'll update to make this more clear. Thanks Ariane!